What does "of" mean when it is at the beginning?
When I check the dictionary, I often see the word "of" at the beginning. Can you explain what it exactly means?
Here's an example of the definition "rare" from a dictionary.

Rare:
(of meat, esp beef) very lightly cooked.


It's not exactly at the beginning because the preposition "of" is written in lowercase, the first word is capitalised Rare followed by a parenthetical note enclosed in brackets.

@Mari-LouA So does it mean "about" in that context?

Yes, nearly, it's a similar meaning. The adjective "rare" is  used to explain or describe  the [level of] doneness of steak, for example.

A sentence with similar use of of is "We may say of meat that it is rare." You could replace of with describing in your example.

So the "of" means "about" in this context, doesn't it? About meat

Yes, or "used to when speaking about".
